# Is there any way to enable El Captain Spotlight features in unsupported countries?

Tags: macos, spotlight

I know that Spotlight Suggestions and Natural Language Search are only available in a few countries.

How does OS X decides if I am in these countries or not? I switched to US locale and region in System Preferences and I use US VPN, so I have US IP Address. But Spotlight features are still disabled.

Is there any way to convince OS X to use these new features?